# Can't run sample code with TestChat from SocketRocket

Tags: ios, websocket, chat, socketserver, socketrocket

I'm launching python server, seems it's working OK, but I can't connect to it from iOS TestChat and I'm receiving `Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused"`

[image]

[SocketRocket iOS client](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket)

[python websocket server on Tornado](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket/blob/master/TestChatServer/py/chatroom.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just didn't noticed in python code right URL to connect:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/chat", ChatHandler),
        (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": args.static_path, "default_filename":'index.html'}),
])
```

So the right URL to connect from iOS client is `[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://localhost:9000/chat"]`